# Merge tags [gnu-make] and [gmake]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

I think [gnu-make](/questions/tagged/gnu-make) and [gmake](/questions/tagged/gmake) should be merged

EDIT: changed gnumake to gnu-make because [gnumake](/questions/tagged/gnumake) is currently remapped to [gnu-make](/questions/tagged/gnu-make). There is already a synonym request [gnu-make](/questions/tagged/gnu-make) <- [gmake](/questions/tagged/gmake) pending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request had been lingering since 2010 and had votes behind it, I went ahead and sent it on  its way.